# Block not loading properly

Tags: magento

I am using Magento var-1.6

I need to add a new template(.html) file to a function. I add a block in the XML, but the page shows the template loaded twice.

This is the code that I added in customer.xml

```
<customer_account_customeraccount translate="label">
    <label>Customer Account Page</label>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="customer_account_page" template="persistent/customer_account.phtml" />
    </reference>
</customer_account_customeraccount>
```

Could any one find the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I guessing correctly that you are trying to replace the template for the block `customer_account_page` ?

In that case you should be able to do:

```
<customer_account_customeraccount translate="label">
    <label>Customer Account Page</label>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="customer_account_page">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>persistent/customer_account.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account_customeraccount>
```